# Send array to ASP.NET from jquery and work with It

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have en array that looks like this:

```
[Object { OldData="(3) Lindrigt skadad",  NewData="(9) Uppgift saknas",  AccidentNumber=1173590}]
```

I make a Jquery-post as below to ASP.NET:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: DataReview.BASE + "/UOS/SaveUOSChangeLog",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data.Result);
            },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        });
```

Here Is my controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveUOSChangeLog(List<String> values)
{
    try
    {
        var fish = Json(new { Data = values });
        return Json(new { Result = "True", ResultData = values }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "Fail", Message = "Faaaaaail" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

When I debug this, the value of `values` is `[0] = "[object Object]"`

How can I access the actually values from the array?

EDIT:

I have created the following model:

```
   public class UOSChangeLogFrontEnd
    {
        public int AccidentNumber { get; set; }
        public string OldData { get; set; }
        public string NewData { get; set; }
        public int Action { get; set; }
    }
```

An my controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveUOSChangeLog(List<UOSChangeLogFrontEnd> values)
        {
            try
            {
                var fish = Json(new { Data = values });
                return Json(new { Result = "True", ResultData = values }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "Fail", Message = "Faaaaaail" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

But the value count Is 0 when I debug.

Comment: The object that you are passing doesn't appear to be a list of values, what if you made a model class that reflects the data you are sending to that controller and then use the class as your parameter for SaveUOSChangelog

Comment: The list of values should not be a String. Create a Model and use it instead

Comment: @Noctane: So I should make a model class with properties that corresponds to the properties in my array?

Comment: @Bryan Yes. That should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a model like this, instead of using `String` as a model.

```
public class AccidentModel
{
    public int AccidentNumber { get; set; }
    public string OldData { get; set; }
    public string NewData { get; set; }
}
```

Then used it in your action like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveUOSChangeLog(AccidentModel accident)
{
    //..use your model
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can't get It work. Check my updated question.

Comment: What's the data in your javascript. Put a breakpoint to check it.

Comment: And try to specify the contentType in your ajax call. Something like this: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: @billybop: What do u mean? When I do a console.log on the array that is posted, It looks like this: [Object { OldData="(3) Lindrigt skadad",  NewData="(11) Avlidit av sjukdom",  AccidentNumber=1173590,  more...}]

Comment: replace List<AccidentModel> accidents by AccidentModel accidents

Comment: billybob: I solved It by setting: data: JSON.stringify({ "values": TableChanges }),

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Model:

```
public class Object
{
    public string OldData { get; set; }
    public string NewData { get; set; }
    public string AccidentNumber { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public Object Object { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveUOSChangeLog(List<RootObject> values)
```

JavaScript:

```
[{
    "Object": {
    "OldData": "(3) Lindrigt skadad",
    "NewData": "(9) Uppgift saknas",
    "AccidentNumber": "1173590"
    }
}]
```